# Playing song through MPMusicPlayerController and using AVCaptureSession at the same time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I have a problem where I have setup an AVCaptureSession with an audio and video input and a capture preview layer. All works great until I try to play a song using MPMusicPlayerController, this instantly makes the preview layer freeze and it is then unable to record the capture session.

Any idea of what I am trying to achieve is actually possible?

Thanks

Comment: 12 years later and still the same issue ....

Answer (score -2):

Well you can  use the variable of stlib.h and assign it to a non-variable deallocated nil object of a layer of a cgpoint * cgpoint, after that what you can do is assign the layer of that to a alocated object with value 3 and then finally assign it to an else of the MPMusicPlayerController/AVCaptureSession

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense.